# SQL server port is blocked on client machine

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2008, proxy, port

I have a client machine on which sql server is installed. This machine is using the internet though a proxy machine. On the proxy machine wingate is installed. I could not connect to the remote sql server through the client machine as proxy machine is blocking the sql server port. Can you please guide me how to unblock the port
On my proxy machine Windows xp is installed and windows firewall is off. 
I can connect to the remote server on proxy machine without any problem.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you first need to check whether TCPIP is enabled for the SQL Server install - go to SQL Server Configuration Manager, look at Network Configuration, look at the protocols used, and look at TCPIP. SQL Server Express disables it by default.

In the same area, right mouse on TCPIP, and check the port used - this is also detailed in the SQL Server log. Also in the Services console, check whether SQL Server Browser is running - this service redirects connections to the correct port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked that TCP/IP is enabled. TCP/IP is using port 1433. I have also enabled the SQL server browser but no success. Any further idea