# SQL server port is blocked on client machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, proxy, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL server port is blocked on client machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/247141/sql-server-port-is-blocked-on-client-machine)

I have a client machine on which sql server is installed. This machine is using the internet though a proxy machine. On the proxy machine wingate is installed. I could not connect to the remote sql server through the client machine as proxy machine is blocking the sql server port. Can you please guide me how to unblock the port On my proxy machine Windows xp is installed and windows firewall is off. I can connect to the remote server on proxy machine without any problem.
i enabled the sql server browser. TCP/IP is enabled in configuration manager. I also tried to change the default port of TCP/IP from 1433 to 80 but no success

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the proxy is preventing anything to go through the 1433 port for SQL Server. The way i'd suggest opening the port would involve going into the firewall and opening 1433, but you said it's disabled. I'd consult whatever the proxy is being run on.